# Difference between Marketing Cloud Administrator and Administrator roles

Tags: marketing-cloud, roles

As mentioned in the title, what's the difference between the 2 roles?
I am aware than the role without "Marketing Cloud prefix" are legacy roles.
I remembered that I used the 2 combined for myself.
What's the rules behind the combination of roles?

Thanks

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5

Comment: So only having the two together you are enabled to do everything, right?